# Alarm ringing just after added in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on an alarm app, the problem is whenever I add a new alarm it starts ringing right after it's created. i've almost checked the code for more than 20 times. and since I have not subscribed to any course no one is there to help except this community.

my mainActivity

```
package com.raunak.alarmdemo4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Activities.AddAlarm;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Adapters.AlarmAdapter;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.HelperClasses.AlarmsDBhelperClass;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Interfaces.AlarmRecyclerViewListener;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Recievers.AlarmReceiver;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AlarmRecyclerViewListener {

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    FloatingActionButton mAlarmAddButton;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    AlarmsDBhelperClass mAlarmsDBhelperClass;
    ArrayList<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <String> modeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> minArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    AlarmAdapter.AlarmView mAlarmView;
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);
    ImageView emptyImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Initializing RecyclerView, DatabaseHelperClass, FAB button, The ON OFF switch & the empty ImageView
        mAlarmsDBhelperClass = new AlarmsDBhelperClass(getApplicationContext());
        mAlarmAddButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAlarmADD);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.alarmList);
        emptyImageView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

        //DividerItemDecoration class is used for getting a vertical line between rows of RecyclerView
        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        //Getting a writable reference of the Database.
        db = mAlarmsDBhelperClass.getWritableDatabase();

        //Retrieving values from the database and storing them in custom ArrayLists
        boolean isDataEmpty = getAlarm(db);

        //SwipeRefreshLayout Initialization
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                alarmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        //Checking if our arrayList is empty? if yes then display some empty list text or an image
        if (!isDataEmpty){
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_alarm_black_white);
            emptyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //FAB Event handling
        mAlarmAddButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.addalarm);
        mAlarmAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddAlarm.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx,int dy){
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (dy >0) {
                    // Scroll Down
                    if (mAlarmAddButton.isShown()) {
                        mAlarmAddButton.hide();
                    }
                }
                else if (dy <0) {
                    // Scroll Up
                    if (!mAlarmAddButton.isShown()) {
                        mAlarmAddButton.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

       //Warping up with the recyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }

    public boolean getAlarm(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM alarms", new String[]{});
        boolean rowExists;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                nameArrayList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                modeArrayList.add(cursor.getString(3));
                repeatArrayList.add(cursor.getString(4));
                hoursArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(5)));
                minArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(6)));
                rowExists = true;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else {
            rowExists = false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return rowExists;
    }


    //RecyclerView's onClick()
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //RecyclerView's onLongClick()
    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {
        //Updating the recyclerView
        alarmAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //Deleting the row from the database
        db.delete("alarms","alarm_name=?",new String[]{nameArrayList.get(position)});

        //Now deleting those values from the mainActivity i.e., ArrayList
        hoursArrayList.remove(position);
        minArrayList.remove(position);
        nameArrayList.remove(position);
        repeatArrayList.remove(position);
        modeArrayList.remove(position);

        //User Feedback
        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSwitchClicked(boolean isStart, int position) {
        if(isStart){
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)));
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)));
            c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            startAlarm(c);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+c.getTime(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            cancelAlarm();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm Turned OFF !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void startAlarm(Calendar c){
        //Getting a System service for the alarm to check the current time with the Alarm set time.
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //Creating an intent to invoke the onReceive method  in the custom receiver class, just to display notifications.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

        //A pending intent is used to execute some work in the future with our applications permissions.
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);

        //Now RTC_WAKEUP means if the device is Switched off turn it on.
        //getTimeInMillis() will get get the time in Milliseconds
        //Schedule an alarm to be delivered precisely at the stated time.In my case it's the calendar's getTimeMillis() method. which is providing the correct time in milliseconds.
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
        Log.d("meme",""+c.getTimeInMillis());
    }



    public void cancelAlarm(){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);

        //Now i'm cancelling the scheduled alarm using AlarmManager's cancel().
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }


}
```

Myboradcast receiver

```
package com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Recievers;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        r.play();
    }
}
```

my Recycler view adapter

```
package com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Adapters;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Interfaces.AlarmRecyclerViewListener;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlarmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmAdapter.AlarmView> {
    //Variables for the main recycler view
    private ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> minArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> modeArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> nameArrayList;
    private AlarmRecyclerViewListener mInterface;

    public AlarmAdapter(ArrayList<String> hours, ArrayList<String> mins, ArrayList<String> mode, ArrayList<String> repeat, ArrayList<String> name, AlarmRecyclerViewListener mInterface){
        this.hoursArrayList = hours;
        this.minArrayList = mins;
        this.modeArrayList = mode;
        this.nameArrayList = name;
        this.repeatArrayList = repeat;
        this.mInterface = mInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlarmView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_profile,parent,false);
        return new AlarmView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmView holder, int position) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)) < 10 ){
            holder.hours.setText("0"+hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.hours.setText(hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)) < 10){
            holder.mins.setText("0"+minArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.mins.setText(minArrayList.get(position));
        }
        holder.repeat.setText(repeatArrayList.get(position));
        holder.mode.setText(modeArrayList.get(position));
        holder.name.setText(nameArrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hoursArrayList.size();
    }

    /*ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            nameArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            modeArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            repeatArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            hoursArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            minArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };*/

    public class AlarmView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView hours,mins,repeat,name,mode;
        Switch mSwitch;
        public AlarmView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hours = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHOUR);
            mins = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMins);
            repeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRepeatDays);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            mode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMode);
            mSwitch =itemView.findViewById(R.id.onoff);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mInterface.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    mInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;
                }
            });

            mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    mInterface.onSwitchClicked(b,getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: remove this: `c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: trying removing, but nothing helped. Thanks for your effort though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be happening is that the alarm you might be setting is in the past and that is why it is triggering immediately

what you can do is shown below

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)));
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)));
    //no need to set like this 
    // c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (c.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); // It is so tell it to run tomorrow instead
    startAlarm(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the problem. In your code

```
 if(isStart){
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)));
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)));
            c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            startAlarm(c);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+c.getTime(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

You used

> c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

That means you set current time of the calendar. and then you `startAlarm(c)` . That's why alarm ringing immediately after created. So remove this line

> c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

I hope it will work/

Comment: Actually I saw this(c.setTimeInMillis)  in the official google's documentation. here's the link https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java

Comment: `setTimeInMillis()` is correct but problem is `System.currentTimeMillis()` and it indicates current time in millisecond format, where as in Calander `setTimeInMillis()` take milisecond but not whole days milisecond. For example: Calender will take: today - 10 hour 5 min 10 second 10  and millisecond and `System.currentTimeMillis()`  contains whole data